# Import TomTom OV2 into Google Maps as My Place Stars

Tags: google-maps

Is there anyway to import my TomTom POVs (saved in an OV2 file) into my google maps account as favorites? i.e. My Places > Starred.

I suspect this may involve converting the OV2 into something else and possibly using google earth or other software.

Answer (score 1):

Global Mapper supports OV2 format (check [here](http://www.bluemarblegeo.com/products/global-mapper-formats-vector.php) for details) so once you insert the OV2 file then you can export this file as (.shp or kml and many other format) suitable format.

I don't have OV2 file at my end but I sure it will help you.

**Download Global Mapper trial version at [here](http://www.bluemarblegeo.com/products/global-mapper-download.php)**